# Oracle dbms_scheduler - react to change of system date

Tags: oracle, dbms-scheduler

I've got a *dbms_scheduler*-Job running in Oracle 10.2.0.

When I change the system date back to yesterday, the job will wait for one day to continue its work. The reason for this is that *next_run_date* does not change.

This does not happen regularly, but sometimes someone decides to change the system date without thinking or even knowing about oracle jobs running.

Any suggestions on how to keep my job running with the configured interval (without having it to change manually)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are changing the system date out from underneath Oracle, your hands might be tied.  Is there a reason you are regularly changing the system date?  If so, perhaps you should create a script for doing so, and have that script also update next_run_date.